# Receive different type of XML request in a orchestration

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a Biztalk which had issues with handling  large XML message requests. So I have planned to use a [custom pipeline component](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180216/Transfer-Large-Files-using-BizTalk-Receive-Side) which saves the message to a temporary directory if the request is more than some specified size, then it creates a small XML which contains path to this temporary large file. If message is small then it sends as it is received.(
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180216/Transfer-Large-Files-using-BizTalk-Receive-Side)

But the problem I am facing now is how to receive this two different schema XML in the orchestration. In my existing orchestration I used to recive XML with specific schema only as I always wanted to get request of specific type. But now I receive XML of two different types. One is the the request XML I receive when size of request is small. One more is the small XML with large file path I receive from pipeline when file size is large.

I tried setting the message type in the recieve side of orchestration to system.xml.xmldocument so that it can receive any type of XML instead of XML with specific schema. It looks to solve the issue but I think this is not ideal solution as it can receive any type of XML request. So I need good approaches to solve the issue mentioned above.

Comment: How big are the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a Listen Shape in your orchestration. Then for each message type, place a receive shape (with Activate = true) in a separate branch of the listen shape.

Comment: Nice. But in that case i will end up with two receive ports i think. But i have only one port now and it receives the original message from source and the pipeline component makes the xml construction as mentioned in question. How to configure the two receive ports for this scenario as source is one location.

Comment: @Navaneet, You can direct bind your orchestration receive port and then create a filter with some specific value (easiest would be your receive port name).

Comment: @Navaneet If the Messages are Typed Message, you don't need to do anything.  Did you try?